# Building a generic collection class

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, generics

I am building the following class to manage a dictionary.

```
    public class EnumDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    {
        private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _Dict;

        public EnumDictionary(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Dict)
        {
            this._Dict = Dict;
        }

        public TKey GetValue(TValue value)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in _Dict)
            {
                if (kvp.Value == value)
                    return kvp.Key;
            }

            throw new Exception("Undefined data type: " + value);
        }              
    }
```

But I am getting an error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TValue' and 'TValue'".

BTW, I am making this custom collection is because my dictionary has unique value, but I can't get key by value from a dictionary.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try using the `Equals` method?

```
if (kvp.Value.Equals(value))
```

I think this restriction is due to the fact that the `==` operator can't be used with all types. Take the following for instance:

```
struct Test
{
    public int Value;
}
```

Given the above struct, the following code will not compile:

```
Test a, b;
a = b = new Test();
bool areEqual = a == b; // Operator '==' cannot be applied to 
                        // operands of type 'Test' and 'Test'
```

However, all types have the `Equals` method, so calling that will work:

```
Test a, b;
a = b = new Test();
bool areEqual = a.Equals(b);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Fredrik is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656303/building-a-generic-collection-class/3656320#3656320); you need to use `Equals` as you can't presume to be able to use `==` for all types, since the operator isn't defined for every type.

Depending on your scenario, it might also make sense to add

```
where TValue : IEquatable<TValue>
```

as a generic type constraint on your class. The reason for this is that `object.Equals` accepts another `object` as a parameter, which means that if `TValue` is a value type it will be boxed. If it can be known to implement `IEquatable<TValue>`, on the other hand, then `Equals` can be resolved to `IEquatable<TValue>.Equals`*, which takes a `TValue` as a parameter and therefore won't require value types to be boxed.

I might *also* recommend that you rethink the internal structure of this class. As it currently stands, there's no reason you need this class at all, as you could easily add an extension method to `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` to find a key by value via enumeration over the values. What I would do instead is store two dictionaries: a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and a `Dictionary<TValue, TKey>`, so that two-way lookup is possible in O(1).

<sub>*By the way, in case you're curious, the reason you can't use `IEquatable<T>` (or any interface for that matter) to ensure that a type has implemented the `==` operator is that operators are *static*, and interfaces cannot provide static methods (and thus can't provide operators).</sub>

Comment: Did you try it? Curiously I cannot get it work unless I'm adding the constraint: `where TValue : class` - http://ideone.com/qdG73 . `IEquatable<TValue>` isn't compiling either.

Comment: @Kobi: Can't get what to work? It sounds like you've misunderstood me; you could get `==` to work if you add the `where TValue : class` constraint because the `==` is defined implicitly for all reference types (it'll just use `object.ReferenceEquals`). What I'm suggesting in my answer is that the OP add `where TValue : IEquatable<TValue>` so that **the `Equals` method** won't box its argument. And yes, I did try this, and it works for me as expected. Is that clear, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Kobi: Yes, I looked at your link and it seems you thought I was saying "if you add `where TValue : IEquatable<TValue>` you can use the `==` operator"... but that's not what I was saying. Hopefully that's clearer now? Or do you think I should reword my answer?

Comment: Obviously, I misunderstood you. Sorry, and thanks for the extra explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you use generic comparsions I think you should implement a (x)CompareTo(Y) or a comparable class. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: You only need this if you require < or > comparisons. If you do then you should implement the IComparable interface and the CompareTo() method. Otherwise the Equals() method (inherited from Object and possibly overridden) works fine.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me. Was a while since i worked with this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "where" condition on your generic types

```
class Dictionary<TKey,TVal>
    where TKey: IComparable, IEnumerable
    where TVal: MyI
{
    public void Add(TKey key, TVal val)
    {
    }
}
```

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use   if (kvp.Value.Equals(value)) instead of ==.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new class. Create a extension method:

```
public static class DictionaryHelper
{
    public static TKey GetKeyFromValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> instance, TValue value)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in instance)
        {
            if (kvp.Value.Equals(value))
                return kvp.Key;
        }
        return default(TKey);
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public static void Main(string[] argv)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Mykey", "MyValue" }, { "Key1", "Value2" } };
        string key = test.GetKeyFromValue("MyValue");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be general purpose, then you will want the definition of equality to be configurable, just as it is in the dictionary for keys.

Have a property of type `IEqualityComparer<TValue>`, which is set in the constructor.

Then have a version of the constructor that makes the default `EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default`. This will work by calling `Equals` on the type in question.

```
public class EnumDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _Dict;
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TValue> _cmp;

    public EnumDictionary(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Dict, IEqualityComparer<TValue> cmp)
    {
        this._Dict = Dict;
        _cmp = cmp;
    }
    public EnumDictionary(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Dict)
        :this(Dict, IEqualityComparer<TValue>.Default){}

    public TKey GetValue(TValue value)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in _Dict)
        {
            if (cmp.Equals(kvp.Value, value))
                return kvp.Key;
        }

        throw new Exception("Undefined data type: " + value);
    }              
}
```